# c++11 construct an object for a caller

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have some `Foo` struct that requires knowledge of some other object's state to be initialized, so I make a factory method for it:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}

  int x_;
};

struct FooFactory {
  Foo MakeFoo() {
    return Foo(++counter);
  }

  int counter = 0;
};
```

So while callers *could* just do `Foo(++factory.counter)`, it's cleaner to be able to just say `factory.MakeFoo()`.

But this code requires copying, and say we want to avoid that. We can use a move constructor instead.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int x) : x_(x) {}
  Foo(Foo& foo) = delete;
  Foo(Foo&& foo) : Foo(foo.x_) { foo.x_ = 0; }

  int x_;
};

struct FooFactory {
  Foo MakeFoo() {
    return Foo(++counter);
  }

  int counter = 0;
};
```

Which works, but still seems like "more" than I want. Something like `Foo foo = factory.MakeFoo()` still creates a temporary inside of `MakeFoo()` and then constructs `foo` via its move constructor.

Is there a way to write this so that `MakeFoo` constructs directly *into* what it's being assigned to?

Comment: You forget that compilers optimize that anyway.

Comment: In case it's not obvious which optimization chris is referring to, Google "return value optimization", or rvo. The compiler is allowed to knit the call to copy constructor and do exactly what you want, as an optimization. The case you presented being simple (single return site), I believe all relevant compilers will optimize it.

Comment: @chris I realize that, but I'm looking at this more from a point of language-level semantics. Is there a way to tell the compiler what I mean instead of having it optimize to what I meant when it can (and potentially not otherwise).

Comment: @alecb with correctly implemented move semantics you should not be afraid of copies. You can also return shared_ptr<Foo>, this way you will not need to be afraid if compiler at some place does not use (N)RVO.

Comment: The first code sample will not copy, but will in fact use the implicitly generated move constructor. To be exact, RVO will elide the move constructor instead of eliding the copy constructor as you claim.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, using *braced-init-list* return for direct initialization of the target object:

```
struct FooFactory {
  Foo MakeFoo() {
    return {++counter};
  }
  // ...
};
```

Note that this will not work if the 1-argument constructor of `Foo` is `explicit`.

> 6.6.3 **[stmt.return]**:
>
> [...] A return statement with a braced-init-list initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer list. [...]

Comment: Uniform initialization ensures that copy ellision (ie initialization of the target object, not a temporary) will be performed allways?

Comment: +1, but I'd remove the word "aggregate" if I were you. It's just initialisation of the return value, it has nothing to do with aggregates.

Comment: @Manu343726 There will be no copy elision, as there will be no copy. This *directly initialises* the return value. It works even with a non-copyable, non-movable type, for example.

Comment: @Angew so there will be no temporary?

Comment: @ecatmur Perhaps I've misunderstood what you meant but it doesn't seem to work for me: http://ideone.com/6m2wAJ

Comment: @alecb Right. This gets rid of *one* temporary, the one which `MakeFoo()` would create and from which it would initialise the return value. There's still the (theoretical) temporary which `main()` uses to initialise `foo`. But in practice, this will of course be elided.

Comment: @Angew Ah, so we still need a move constructor defined?

Comment: @alecb not if you bind the return value of `MakeFoo()` to a rvalue reference: `Foo&& foo(factory.MakeFoo());`

Comment: @ecatmur Or a `const Foo&`, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

While I would not suggest it, a macro is a valid solution:

```
#define MAKE_FOO() Foo(++factory.counter)
```

or for initialization of class members or locals:

```
#define INIT_FOO(x) x(++factory.counter)
```